# MSMQ:Is there a way to know the queue is deleted and created again when the other process is updating messages?

Tags: msmq

I have the a process to write message to a queue and the other program reads message and process them. While the user manually deletes the queue and then recreate it again while the writing process is running. On the process end, we do not receive any new message and on writing end, we do not see any error either. Question is if there is way to handle such cases?

Comment: Are you sending to, and receiving from, a local or remote queue?

Comment: it is local private queue.